# merge results from 2 datasets from 2 different databases in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two SQL Server 2008 databases and am using SSRS 2008 R2. in DB1 I have a list of ALL rooms with services that occupy those rooms. Some of these rooms do not have a service recorded against them. These rooms (and their services) are recorded in DB2.

In DB2 I have small number of rooms with a list of services that use those rooms. The rooms that appear in the DB2 are present in DB1, but in DB1 they do not have any services recorded against them.

I want to merge the results from both datasets into one tablix so that I show all rooms from DB1 plus the rooms from DB2 so that all rooms show services against them. Just wondering what the best way to do this is? I have a field on both DBs that match. DB1.RESOURCES.ROOM_NAME & DB2.ROOMS.DB2_ROOM_NAME. But this is really the only similarity as both DBs have different table and field names.

Would I just use a join on DB1.RESOURCES.ROOM_NAME = DB2.ROOMS.DB2_ROOM_NAME

Or should I use Lookup function here.

Any guidance on how to achieve would be appreciated.

Comment: Does https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31414.ssrs-merge-data-from-different-datasources-into-one-dataset-inside-ssrs-report.aspx or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360641/combining-the-information-from-two-datasets-in-ssrs-r2-2008?rq=1 help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have a tablix have two data sets.  The easiest way around this would be a T-SQL stored procedure where you have a linked database server between DB1 and DB2 and you can then reference that table from DB1 in DB2.  So it will have some code like:

```
SELECT d.ColA, d.ColB, d.ColC
FROM dbo.MyTable d
UNION ALL
SELECT b.ColA, b.ColB,b.ColC
DROM DB1.dbo.MyOtherTable b
```

Below you will find more information on Linked Servers:

[Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)