# Combining the Information from two datasets in SSRS R2 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am fairly new to ssrs r2 2008. What I am trying to do is create a funnel chart which displays the combined revenue information from two tables in different databases but on the same server. Doing my own research, I have found that I could use the lookup function, but I am not sure where I would implement this function. I have done research, but I haven't found any documentation which explicitly explains how and where lookup can be implemented.

What I have so far is two datasources which reference each database, and two datasets with each dataset referencing each datasource. Both datasets have the same field names as the tables in the database have the same fields, so I can basically perform the lookup on any field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to merge the data "vertically" (as with a UNION statement in SQL) or "horizontally" (as with a join?)

Comment: I am looking to merge the data vertically, as I basically want to have all the data from the two tables combined together, given they have the same fields. @AnnL.

Comment: You said the databases were on the same server.  Do you have a single user id that can access both databases, or do you have to use different users and passwords for the two data sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to `UNION` the rows from each table together. Since you are going across databases, you need to include the database name in the table reference for the table that the dataset's data source isn't connected to:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM OtherDatabase.dbo.OtherTable
```

You need to make sure that the account that the report is running under has access to both databases.

Comment: It might also pay to fully qualify the first table with a database.schema as well

Comment: I originally wrote it like that but if that is the database that the datasource is connected to you don't really need to. It could be useful for clarity purposes however.